# iOS - GMSMapView - How to add a grid that zooms with map

Tags: ios, gmsmapview

Is there a way to add a grid to a GMSMapView such that as you zoom/move the map the grid zooms/moves with it? (the grid is fixed relative to the map)

Basically I am trying to encapsulate every square kilometer in a grid block

Example:

[image]